# Generating Random numbers with a known seed value

Tags: python, random-seed

I am debugging a 64-bit Linux ELF binary which uses time() to generate a seed. Then this seed is used by srand() to seed the random number generator. And rand() is used to generate the random number.

I have the value of the seed and now I am trying to reproduce the same result as the binary.

```
seed = 0x93ae5c6

srand(seed)

rand() returns 0x000000003173C91C
```

If I use Python to generate the random number, I get a different result

```
import random
random.seed(0x93ae5c6)
random.random() returns 0.8019104241491927
```

Is it because Python generates random numbers in a different way than glibc on Linux?

Comment: Yes, python uses a different rng. Plus the methods you are using are not really comparable.

Comment: Is there a way to reproduce the results using Python? or should I compile a binary using gcc on Linux and maybe that will generate the same random numbers? Does the random number generator depend on the libc version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
[Python port of the GLIBC rng](https://gist.github.com/integeruser/4cca768836c68751904fe215c94e914c)